# Cannot modify path mapping in PhpStorm - Project files are not being detected

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Greetings to everyone,

I'm facing a problem when I cannot setup the path mappings. Debug starts but because of missing mappings I cannot reach any breakpoints.

here is how my configuration looks like:

[image]

I cannot select mapping on the server and nothing is available there (not clickable)

Comment: Is it 2024.1 EAP build? If so -- it's a known issue, already fixed for next EAP builds: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-75914

Comment: >Is it 2024.1 EAP build? 

yes it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was correctly pointed out by @LazyOne in the comments it is a known [issue for 2024.1 EAP build](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-75914)

This is exactly the case for me, unfortunately